# Cask without pallet

Tags: package, cask

At some point, I found a web page that described using `Cask` and `Pallet` to configure emacs.  I got that working, and life was good.  I recently upgraded my version of `Cask` to 0.9.0, and now I find this in `cask.el`:

```
(define-obsolete-function-alias 'cask-initialize nil "22.1"
  "In particular, I would not =require cask= in your dot.emacs
since cask is now largely a command-line tool independent of
whatever you do within emacs.  If you are calling
=cask-initialize= in your dot.emacs or harken back to the bygone
era of [[https://github.com/rdallasgray/pallet][pallet]], I'm
afraid you're on your own.")
```

My `.emacs` does indeed have `(require 'cask "/path/to/cask.el") (cask-initialize))`

Given that the most recent change in [pallet](https://github.com/rdallasgray/pallet) is 6 years ago, it's clear that I've fallen behind current practices.  However, when I search for things like "emacs cask without pallet", all I find is advice on how to configure emacs with `cask` and `pallet`.

I was able to get things working with

```
(let* ((cask-source-list '("~/.cask/cask.el" "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/cask/cask.el"))
       (cask-source (cl-find-if #'file-exists-p cask-source-list)))
  (when cask-source
    (require 'cask cask-source)
    (cask--initialize)))
```

(Note the double dash in the initialize call.) However, since the comment specifically advises against requiring `cask`, I feel this is still not current best practice.

What is the current best practice for managing packages?

I am happy with either "go to this web page, which explains it" or "add these three lines to the start of your `.emacs`".

If the answer is "don't use cask; use this [link here] instead", that also works, especially if there is a simple way to migrate my installed packages to the new system.

Comment: Your question may be interpreted as starting opinionated responses - however, take a look at this https://github.com/progfolio/elpaca, this package is already built-in into Emacs 29.

Answer (score 0):

Cask is no longer intended to be package management tool, it's more of a bundler for dependency management. Think Python virtual environments. Or for a developer to test an Emacs package with different combinations of Emacs and dependent packages, as in a CI environment. There's a [known issue](https://github.com/cask/cask/issues/579) with respect to the docs, and [they mention it in the faq](https://github.com/cask/cask#frequently-asked-questions).

---

Emacs has it's own package manager `package.el`. It's basic but gets the job done. The afore mentioned [Elpaca](https://github.com/progfolio/elpaca) is a big improvement.

[`El-get`](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) is a popular option and has been around a while. It uses `package.el` on its backend. I have no experience with it though.

[`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is a macro to help you configure and load packages in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, and uses `package.el` on the backend too. It's authored by one of the Emacs maintainers, who claims it's "not a package manager".

[`straight.el`](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el) is a package manager built on top of `use-package`.

[`leaf.el`](https://github.com/conao3/leaf.el) "leaf.el is yet another use-package". Reading about it, it sounds like a re-implemented `use-package` with similar keywords and semantics. Could be an interesting option for current users of `use-package`.

Comment: I personally use `use-package`. Simple and does what I want. I rarely need to "manage" packages. I just need them loaded and configured.